# Finding the last iteration in a while loop (PHP & MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a leaderboard type thing. And I need the last iteration of the loop to be a different CSS style to the rest, I've looked around but I can't really find a precise answer.

My code:

```
$kills = mysql_query("SELECT victim,rankid FROM kills WHERE victim != 'Tony' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10");

while($lasttenkilled = mysql_fetch_assoc($kills)){
$name = $lasttenkilled['victim'];

echo"<tr><td class='te'><font size=1>&nbsp;</font><a href=viewprofile.php?username=$name>$name</a></td></tr>"; 
}?>
```

I need the last `<tr><td>` to be `<td class=endte><br>`.

And yes, I'm using MySQL; I'm planning on changing to mysqli, so inb4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //Change All this to mysqli_*  



    $kills = mysql_query("SELECT victim,rankid FROM kills WHERE victim != 'Tony' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10");
        $killNum = mysql_num_rows($kills);

       $i=0;
        while($lasttenkilled = mysql_fetch_assoc($kills)){
//your class goes here
$tdClass = $i==$killNum ? "yourClass" : "";
        $name = $lasttenkilled['victim'];

        echo"<tr><td class='$tdClass'><font size=1>&nbsp;</font><a href=viewprofile.php?username=$name>$name</a></td></tr>";
$i++;
        }
```

checking num rows and checking last looped value using increment i and num rows from sql.